# How can i define inline shape condition as an if statement in pine scipt

Tags: pine-script

```
plotshape(lower_breakout ? high[length] : na,"Lower Break",shape.labeldown,location.absolute,#ef5350,-length,text="short", textcolor=color.white,size=size.tiny)
```

Comment: Do you want to be able to change the shape depending on a condition?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a ternary operator by inline shape condition, then you need to create a variable and reassign a new value to it in the if/else statement.
Ternary operator consists of: `logical expression ? return value when true : return value when false`

And in the plotshape function, display this variable as a series argument

```
float result = na
if lower_breakout
    result := high[length]
plotshape(result,"Lower Break",shape.labeldown,location.absolute,#ef5350,-length,text="short", textcolor=color.white,size=size.tiny)
```

You can find general principles and examples of how ternary operators work on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).